# How to do URL rewrite for all URLs except a specific URL using Nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have deployed my web application in Nginx 1.8 and also using Nginx for a reverse proxy configuration.

I want the following to happen. I am able to achieve 1 & 2. How can i get the 5 implemented in an Nginx configuration ? 3 & 4 are sample scenarios of scenario 5

1. URL http://localhost in browser --> Have to display index.html
2. URL http://localhost/app  --> Have to proxy_pass to http://localhost:8081
3. URL http://localhost/login      --> Have to display index.html as http://localhost
4. URL http://localhost/dashboard      -->   Have to display index.html  as http://localhost
5. URL http://localhost/Anything_Other_than_app --> Have to display
   index.html  as http://localhost

my problem is, this index.html has a Login functionality, on successful, login it redirects user to a URL http://localhost/dashboard and displays list of users. If any user name is clicked, it redirets to http://localhost/user to display their details.

***UseCase:*** Now if i directly type the http://localhost/dashboard or http://localhost/user URL, Nginx is searching for this folder and a index page under my root and giving 404 error. Instead, what i want is to display the Index.html page, which has the logic to display the list of users or the login page based on the session exists or not.

***Solution We Used***:

```
location = /index.html {
         root   myTestApp;
        }
        location ~* .*\.png$ {
         root   myTestApp;
        }
        location ~* .*\.jpg$ {
         root   myTestApp;        
        }
        location ~* .*\.css$ {
         root   myTestApp;        
        }
        location ~* .*\.gif$ {
         root   myTestApp;        
        }
        location ~* .*\.js$ {
         root   myTestApp;
        }   

        location / {
            root   myTestApp;
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html;          
        }  

      location /app {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;              

        }
```

Comment: And you really don't have css, scripts, images?

Comment: i have added the usecase for why i had this question. Hope this makes the question more clear. The web application is a node.js application which has css, images & js files in it.

Answer (score 1):

Easy

```
location / {
    try_files /index.html =404;
}

location /app/ {
    # proxy to your app
}
```

Comment: when i used this is still giving 404. what could be wrong ?   **bold** code location / {
            root   myPOC;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files index.html =404;
           
        } code **bold**       (myPOC is my web app folder in c:\nginx-1.8.0)

Comment: You should always use absolute path in `root` directive.

Comment: You've missed slash in `try_files` and you don't need `index`

Comment: looks like there is still some problem. i removed the index and used try_files /index.html =404 but, now i am getting a blank page. using this configuration, are we trying to force nginx to use index.html file as the 404 error page ?

Comment: How do you know it's blank?